# Binding list of objects to ItemsControl with custom ItemTemplate in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grouping, itemscontrol

## Current Setup

I have a custom class representing an installer file and some properties about that file, conforming to the following interface

```
public interface IInstallerObject
{
    string FileName { get; set; }
    string FileExtension { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }
    int Build { get; set; }
    ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    Architecture ArchType { get; set; }
    bool Configurable { get; set; }
    int AverageInstallTime { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

My `ViewModel` has a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IInstallerObject>` property named `AvailableInstallerObjects`.

My `View` has a `GroupBox` containing the `ItemsControl` which binds to the aforementioned property.

```
    <GroupBox Header="Products">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableInstallerObjects}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
```

The binding works correctly, except it's not user friendly. 100+ items are shown.

## Need Help Here

I'd like to be able to use my collection of `IInstallerObject`s but have the `View` present them with the following `ItemTemplate` structure.

```
    <GroupBox Header="Products">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableInstallerObjects}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductType}" Margin="5" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Build}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
```

Basically I want to be able to group by the `ProductType` property, showing a list of the available products, with the `ComboBox` representing the available `Build` property values for `IInstallerObject`s of the `ProductType`.

I can use `LINQ` in the `ViewModel` to extract the groupings, but I have no idea how I'd bind to what I've extracted.

My research also turned up the possibility of using a `CollectionViewSource` but I'm not certain on how I can apply that to my current setup.

*I appreciate your help in advance. I'm willing to learn so if I've overlooked something obvious please direct me to the information and I'll gladly educate myself.*

Answer (score 0):

If Build should be a collection type.

so your class should be structured like this as an example.

```
Public Class Customer
 Public Property FirstName as string
Public Property LastName as string
Public Property CustomerOrders as observableCollection(OF Orders)
End Class
```

This should give you the expected results. Each item in the main items presenter will show first name last name and combobox bound to that  customers orders.
I know it's simple but this should do.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is declare a `CollectionViewSource` in your view and bind it to the `ObservableCollection`. Within this object you declare one or more `GroupDescriptions` which will split up the source into several groups.

Bind this source to the listbox, create a Template for the group description and you are done.

An example can be found here: [WPF Sample Series – ListBox Grouping, Sorting, Subtotals and Collapsible Regions](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/wpf-sample-series-listbox-grouping-sorting-subtotals-and-collapsible-regions/). More about CollectionViewSource can be found here: [WPF’s CollectionViewSource](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387)

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem lead me to believe you are looking for some kind of colapsing / expanding / grouped / tree-view sort of thing.

XAML for the tree-view

```
<Window x:Class="WPFLab12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WPFLab12"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
      <GroupBox Header="Products">
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductTypes}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    DataType="{x:Type loc:ProductType}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableInstallerObjects}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:InstallerObject}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
      </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What does that do? Well, it establishes a hierarchy of controls in the tree based on the type of data found. The first `HierarchicalDataTemplate` handles how to display the data for each class, and how they are related in the hierarchy. The second `HierarchicalDataTemplate` handles how to display each `InstallerObject`.

Code behind for the Main Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ProductType> ProductTypes
    {
        get { return (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ProductType>)GetValue(ProductTypesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProductTypesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ProductTypes.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductTypesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ProductTypes", typeof(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ProductType>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ProductTypes = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ProductType>(
            new ObservableCollection<ProductType>()
            {
                new ProductType() 
                { 
                    Description = "Type A",
                    AvailableInstallerObjects = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<InstallerObject>(
                        new ObservableCollection<InstallerObject>()
                        {
                            new InstallerObject() { FileName = "A" },
                            new InstallerObject() { FileName = "B" },
                            new InstallerObject() { FileName = "C" },
                        })
                },

                new ProductType() 
                { 
                    Description = "Type B",
                    AvailableInstallerObjects = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<InstallerObject>(
                        new ObservableCollection<InstallerObject>()
                        {
                            new InstallerObject() { FileName = "A" },
                            new InstallerObject() { FileName = "D" },
                        })
                }
            });

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

This is totally cheating, though - normally the `MainWindow.cs` would not serve as the DataContext and have all this stuff. But for this example I just had it make a list of `ProductType`s and populate each `ProductType` class with the `InstallerObject` instances.

Classes I used, note I made some assumptions and modified your class to suit this View Model better:

```
public class InstallerObject
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Build { get; set; }
    public bool Configurable { get; set; }
    public int AverageInstallTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<InstallerObject> AvailableInstallerObjects
    {
        get;
        set; 
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }
}
```

So, in MVVM, it seems to me that your current `InstallerObject` class is more of a Model layer sort of thing. You might consider transforming it in your ViewModel to a set of collection classes that are easier to manage in your View. The idea in the ViewModel is to model things similarly to how they are going to be viewed and interracted with. Transform your flat list of `InstallerObjects` to a new collection of hierarchical data for easier binding to the View.

More info on various ways to use and customize your TreeView: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF